Replacement for ListViewGroups and ListViewItem.DataItemIndex from NET 4.5.1 to NET 8.0
I am migrating an .NET application from .NET 4.5.1 to .NET 8.0 and I found out that these two things do not exist anymore. Are there any replacements for the ListViewGroups and ListViewItem.DataItemIndex?
listView.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup());

listViewItem.Group = listViewName.Groups[variable];

I haven't found any kind of replacement at the moment.

Welcome. No such thing as ListViewItem.DataItemIndex in WinForms. That's WebControls thing. Please validate your tags.
